# Converting HTML to Pdf with iTextSharp - invalid nested p tag found

Tags: html, vb.net, pdf, itext

Here is my code:

```
Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(args(0))
Dim htmlStr As String = sr.ReadToEnd
sr.Close()

Using document As Document = New Document()
   Using writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New FileStream("C:\Test\myfile.pdf", FileMode.Create))
      document.Open()
      XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, New StringReader(htmlStr)) <--Error here
   End Using
   document.Close()
End Using
```

Can anyone help me figure out what can I do to fix this? The htm file I am reading looks fine and also there is nothing I can do to change the file itself.

Comment: Bruno's got the answer but I wanted to address what you said about not being able to change the file itself. You might not be able to change the file but you can inject a process between the file and iText's handling of it. If you're HTML is relatively simple you might be able to get away with some string replacements or you could look into something like [Tidy.Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidynet/) or another HTML cleaner upper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message explains what is going wrong: the error is in your HTML.

You have a `<p>` tag somewhere, and it is followed by another closing tag (only you can tell us which tag) that is not `</p>`.

For instance:

This would be correct [1]:

```
<p>This is a paragraph<br />with a new line</p>
```

However, this would be incorrect [2]:

```
<p>This is a paragraph</br>with an incorrect new line</p>
```

This is also invalid [3]:

```
<b>Some bold text <p>inside a paragraph</b> that is not correctly nested.</p>
```

The parser will understand [1], but throw the error you get when you have [2] or [3].

Comment: Hi Bruno. I replace all <br> tags with <br/>. Now I am getting an error "invalid nested div tag found expected closing tag hr". I have tried replacing <hr> with <hr/> but it still give me the same error

Comment: So you are saying that my answer fixed one problem, but that you are now experiencing another problem. Are you aware of the fact that nobody but you can help you? You say that you have replaced every `<hr>` instance with `<hr />`, but your XML parser says that you didn't. I believe your XML parser and so should you. (I hope you understand that this has nothing to do with iTextSharp: it's an XHTML problem.)